# Escape input in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT, which formats the output by grouping keys on a given array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">


    <xsl:param name="values" select="'Sniper 50 Red', 'Xiper 10 Red'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:match" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="values" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="if ($values[matches($input, concat('^', .))])
                    then $values[matches($input, concat('^', .))]
                    else $input"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="pageFunctionResult" group-by="mf:match(product_name, $values)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="product_name ne current-grouping-key()">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <position>MAINPRODUCT</position>
                                <variantname>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="product_name"/>
                                </variantname>
                                <product_namea>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                                </product_namea>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="category, product_id, quantity, manufacturer,image"/>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <position>MAINPRODUCT</position>
                            <variantname>
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </variantname>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pageFunctionResult">
        <variant id="{position()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </variant>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Here you can see [it in action](http://xsltransform.net/ncntCS6/2). It works well, but I now have keys with bracket in their names:

```
<xsl:param name="values" select="'Sniper 50 Red (26)', 'Xiper 10 Red (27)'"/>
```

...and this obviously brakes the code, because brackets are reserved in regex. So the brackets should be escaped. I got a tip to use [functx:escape-for-regex](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_escape-for-regex.html), but I am unable to implement it to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how to use the `functx` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf functx">

    <xsl:param name="values" select="'Sniper 50 Red (26)', 'Xiper 10 Red (27)'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:escape-for-regex" as="xs:string"
        >
        <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="
            replace($arg,
            '(\.|\[|\]|\\|\||\-|\^|\$|\?|\*|\+|\{|\}|\(|\))','\\$1')
            "/>

    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:match" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="values" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="if ($values[matches($input, concat('^', functx:escape-for-regex(.)))])
            then $values[matches($input, concat('^', functx:escape-for-regex(.)))]
            else $input"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="pageFunctionResult" group-by="mf:match(product_name, $values)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="product_name ne current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <position>MAINPRODUCT</position>
                            <variantname>
                                <xsl:value-of select="product_name"/>
                            </variantname>
                            <product_namea>
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </product_namea>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="category, product_id, quantity, manufacturer,image"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <position>MAINPRODUCT</position>
                                <variantname>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                                </variantname>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pageFunctionResult">
        <variant id="{position()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </variant>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: The function is taken from http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html, I did not try to change it as the main suggestion was to use the library function and then to show how to do it as the poster said he did not know how. I agree your versions looks more compact and efficient.